# 400 Bad Request on MEAN

Tags: javascript, angular, express, mean

so I'm posting this question after a hours of research .... That's the answer of the browser and I can't find any reason why... 
So, after the login, I want to fetch the score of the user logged. The score is located in a subtable of the user table (Mongo ...). But the call for the server doesn't work. Here is my code :

login.component.ts

```
this.dbService.scoresDownload(this.username).subscribe(scoresDownload => {
                console.log(scoresDownload);
              });
```

db.service.ts

```
  scoresDownload(username) {
this.createAuthenticationHeaders();
console.log(username)
return this.http.post(this.domain + 'training/scoresDownload', username, this.options).map(res => res.json());
```

}

training.js (route in Express)

```
          router.post('/scoresDownload', (req, res) => {

// let wordScoresDb = [];
console.log(req)

User.find({}, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    res.json({ success: false, message: err }); // Return connection error
  } else {
    res.json({ success: true, message: result }); // Return as vailable username
  }
})});
```

It works well if I use a get instead of a post .... And the most tricky part is that it works with all my other calls. So, I really don't know where I mess up ...
Cheers guys !

EDIT :
I forgot to mention the error sent by express

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
at Object.parse (native)
at createStrictSyntaxError (D:\Code\Deutsch_App_MEAN\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:157:10)
at parse (D:\Code\Deutsch_App_MEAN\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
at D:\Code\Deutsch_App_MEAN\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
at invokeCallback (D:\Code\Deutsch_App_MEAN\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
at done (D:\Code\Deutsch_App_MEAN\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (D:\Code\Deutsch_App_MEAN\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... I miserably found the answer ... the username I was passing through MEAN is a string ... Apparently the "post" from the http module does accept only object or array, and not string ... Voilà :)